# Clash of Clans Game Center ID

Tags: clash-of-clans

I want to change user ids in clash of clans.  Can I do that without restoring the ipad to factory settings?

Comment: Can you just sign out of Game Center?

Comment: You dont need game center

Comment: Couldn't you link it to another account on a separate device?

Answer (score 2):

Just sign out of game center, then create another account.

However, if you want to keep your base AND change your user ID, you can't. Super cell does not allow you to change your username as it might affect the online server that COC is based on.

If you don't have a game-center, then you can just delete the game and re install it.

Comment: There must be some sort of back up server as they can restore lost bases?

Comment: Yes, any other device other than apple automatically backs up your base to their server if you would delete it. That is why I added the last part, because I was implying that this would work on devices without gamecenter.